# Is there a better way of doing multiprocessing than this? Preferably faster and not so hard on the memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

This is my code. I don't think this is the best way to do this task, Can you kindly help me? Thanks in advance. It responded once but when I ran it again it kept on running and didn't give out the desired output.
Edit: I have added the missing code, platform wasn't allowing me to post it as there is too much code and too little description.

```
Q=Queue()
Q1=Queue()
Q2=Queue()
Q3=Queue()
Q4=Queue()
Q5=Queue()
Q6=Queue()
Q7=Queue()
Q8=Queue()
p0=  Process(target=weatherSearch,args=(city,Q,))
p2=  Process(target=holidays,args=(city,Q2,))
p3=  Process(target=constructUniversity,args=(school,company,Q3,))
p4=  Process(target=constructsignature,args=(Q4,))
p5=  Process(target=constructCTA,args=(Q5,))
p6=  Process(target=profile,args=(df,Q6,))
p7=  Process(target=google_news,args=(company,Q7,))
p8=  Process(target=financial_news,args=(company,Q8,))






p0.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
p5.start()
p6.start()
p7.start()
p8.start()

p0.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()
p5.join()
p6.join()
p7.join()
p8.join()
result=Q.get()
temperature=result["temp"][0]
conditions=result["weather_description"][0]
holidays=Q2.get()
constructuniversity=Q3.get()
signature=Q4.get()
CTA=Q5.get()
general_news=Q7.get()
finance=Q8.get()
resul=Q6.get()
myers_briggs=resul[0]
rules=resul[1]
better_understanding=resul[2]
personality_type=resul[3]
```

Comment: You are missing the multiprocessing part in your code.

Comment: I have added the missing code, this is the complete code. Kindly view it, thanks

Comment: This is not the best way to present a minimal reproducible example of your problem. Maybe enhance the code and offer an explanation of the use-case

Comment: That is not the complete code. Even if the variables (city, school etc) were declared it couldn't run due to the absence of your functions (weatherSearch, holidays etc). It also looks as though you've assumed that the only way to get output from a sub-process is via a queue. That is not the case

Comment: @JCaesar I have 9 functions, that I want to run in parallel. I have added the missing code as requested. I am still learning how to use stack overflow properly and be a valuable member of this platform.

Comment: @JCaesar a Dataframe is created in the main class, and company, school etc. variables are declared. The code works, but performance is not up to the mark and it hangs every other time. Queues seemed to be the easiest way to get the return values of the functions.

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at the Manager and ProcessPoolExecutor classes. In the absence of complete code I can't provide you with a functional Answer. However, if you want to get onto Chat, I'll help you

Comment: @JCaesar how can we get into chat? I have looked at Manager but didn't quite understand it as it was more useful with communication between processes. The full code is more than 600 lines and uses several APIs to perform tasks. It takes like 5 minutes to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241246/discussion-between-jcaesar-and-sardar-arslan).

Answer (score 1):

I want to preface this by saying, your solution doesn't necessarily have any problems with it as long as it works as you expect it to.

I would re-structure your functions to simply return their results rather than putting the results each to their own `Queue`, then use a `multiprocessing.Pool` to call the functions (because it will handle passing args and results back and forth for you). I would also get in the habit of using the `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause in case you aren't already. It makes your code less likely to fail if you try to run it on another computer.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #in general don't create processes outside this if statement [calling Pool() creates processes as well as simply Process()]
    #This will make your code more compatible with Windows and MacOS (with python later than 3.6 iirc)
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        #Call functions asynchronously then call .get() on the async result to get the return value when it becomes available.
        result_async = pool.apply_async(weatherSearch, (city,))
        holidays_async = pool.apply_async(holidays, (city,))
        constructuniversity_async = pool.apply_async(constructUniversity, (school, company))
        signature_async = pool.apply_async(constructsignature)
        CTA_async = pool.apply_async(constructCTA)
        general_news_async = pool.apply_async(google_news, (company,))
        finance_async = pool.apply_async(financial_news, (company,))
        resul_async = pool.apply_async(profile, (df,))
        
        result = result_async.get()
        temperature=result["temp"][0]
        conditions=result["weather_description"][0]
        holidays=holidays_async.get()
        constructuniversity=constructuniversity_async.get()
        signature=signature_async.get()
        CTA=CTA_async.get()
        general_news=general_news_async.get()
        finance=finance_async.get()
        resul=resul_async.get()
        myers_briggs=resul[0]
        rules=resul[1]
        better_understanding=resul[2]
        personality_type=resul[3]
```

The usage is a little cleaner than creating a bunch of unique `Queue`'s, and I would stick to more descriptive names than things like `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, etc.. Finally I would like to point out, that if you stick with your original solution, you should "`get`" the results from the `Queue`'s before "`join`ing" the processes. It's extremely unlikely to happen with how you're using them, but in theory this could cause a process to get stuck and never shut down (and then the main process would be stuck waiting for `join`). In practice the fix is as simple as moving all the `join` statements to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, Sir.